# packaging sequences of png files in iPhone APP for animations to reduce bundle size

Tags: iphone, video, animation, uikit, png

Basically, I have an application that uses a flip-book style animation technique.  I am simply cycling through around 1000 320x480 pngs at 12fps, and everything works really well.  Except for the fact that 1000 images takes up a ton of disk space.  Ideally I'd like to be able to compress these images as a movie file and pull out each frame as I need them, or simply play back a movie with frame by frame precision.

Ideas?